# Javascript onLoad on Safari keeps Loading

Tags: javascript, safari, onload

I have a javascript function that I want to call when the page loads. So I called the function using the body onLoad tag -

```
<body onload="function();" >
```

This works, but on the Safari browser, the application continues to show the loading symbol even after the function has finished execution. When I call the same function using a button click on the page, Safari behaves nicely and doesn't show the loading symbol after the function's execution.

I tested on Chrome and Firefox and I don't see this problem. I've also tried other ways of calling it on load -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
$(document).onload(function() {
});
```

But the problem persists on Safari. Any ideas ?

Comment: Function contains the stuff I want to execute onLoad. It contains simple stuff like changing the DOM contents ...